# Java VM memory initialization in JavaFX project

Tags: memory, jvm

My JavaFX project's `JVM: Xms=768m` *(my program has high requirement on the memory),* when the memory is not enough, my program can't be started with error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Error: could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred.Program will exit.

Eclipse console output：

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Has any way to start my program even if the left memory is not enough?
If not, has some better way for memory initialization in JavaFX project?
Maybe some PC have only 1G RAM, I still want to install my program on them.

Comment: Could get the main features of you program?

Comment: Pure C/S architecture with OSGI, run many TCL scripts on many devices by multi-threads, so we need a 2G RAM PC to run.

Answer (score 0):

If your operating system supports virtual memory (all modern consumer OSes do, but some embedded systems do not), you should be able to run your application even if you don't have much physical memory, albeit at a huge performance penalty due to paging to/from the disk.  If you're running a 32-bit JVM, it's possible you've somehow requested the heap be larger than the virtual address space available (either by passing -Xmx or passing some GC tuning flags), but you haven't provided enough information to know whether that's the case.